# How to keep the value of a variable current throughout multiple React Native components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a `Parent` React Native component which is composed of three children components, `Header`, `Body`, and `Footer`. This is how it is arranged inside a file `MyScreen.js`:

```
<Container>    // I am using NativeBase Container

  <Header />
  <Body />
  <Footer />

</Container>
```

Definitions of these three children components are contained in separate files, e.g. `Body.component.js`, and so on.

I want to access an array data structure `Foo` contained in a different file `FooArray.js`, and it is imported by both `Body` and `Footer` components. `Foo` is manipulated inside the `Body` component (I `push()` objects to this array here) and its length `Foo.length` is displayed in the `Footer` component.

**How can I make sure that whenever a new object is pushed to `Foo` in the `Body` component, its new length is immediately reflected in the separate `Footer` component?**

Any ideas, regarding not only the expected solution but also optimal re-structuring of the project files if needed, are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React solves this problem with state.

You import your data (foo) into a top level component (Container) and assign it to the state.  Then you can pass the state  down to children components as props.

All the children components can use these props and will automatically update if the prop changes.

If you want to make changes to the state from within the children components, you should pass handler functions (defined in the parent component) to the children components as props.